# Android Gmail app does not render background image in HTML email

Tags: android, html, email, gmail

HTML email. Everyone's first and last love.

I've built an table-based email that has a background image with text overlay as a 'hero' module. I used a background image on a div w/ inline CSS. Works great everywhere except Outlook 2010/2013, and Android Gmail native app.

Did android gmail app stop supporting background images?

Even this didn't work... bulletproof sample(backgrounds.cm) to illustrate and litmus says no go on outlook and android gmail app.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td background="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQNR9_Ru7wFZQLYHFXkeobjz0VoSFcC6-ieN7yWBa0dsnHhvZ8-IPSmpKw" bgcolor="#7bceeb" width="580" height="240" valign="top">
  <!--[if gte mso 9]>
  <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:580px;height:240px;">
    <v:fill type="fill" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQNR9_Ru7wFZQLYHFXkeobjz0VoSFcC6-ieN7yWBa0dsnHhvZ8-IPSmpKw" color="#7bceeb" />
    <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
  <![endif]-->
  <div>
      Please work, please, darn it
        </div>
  <!--[if gte mso 9]>
    </v:textbox>
  </v:rect>
  <![endif]-->
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Just wondering if you managed to find a fix for this? I'm having similar issues.

Comment: They ended up using an image.

Answer (score 1):

Good question.  There's a lot of conflicting information about this topic.

For instance, [this link](https://litmus.com/help/email-clients/gmail-no-head/) suggests to inline all CSS, whereas [this link](https://litmus.com/blog/understanding-gmail-and-css-part-1) suggests to embed all styles in the head.  And even further - if [this link](https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/12_things_you_must_know_when_developing_for_gmail_and_gmail_mobile_apps) is correct, Gmail's e-mail preprocessor strips sketchy-looking CSS from the email body altogether:

> Gmail doesn't allow backgrounds (mostly). If you include any reference to a URL, your entire declaration will be ignored. For example:
>
> `background: #000;  /*This will be accepted */`
>
> `background: #000 url(http://www.test.com/test.jpg); /* This entire line will be ignored */`

---

Anyway, I had a similar issue involving a background image not working on a `<table>` element, which I resolved* by way of adding a class to my table ...

```
<table class="table">
```

... with an accompanying stylesheet declaration:

```
<style>
    .table {
        background-image: url(https://www.example.com/image.jpg/);
    }
</style>
```

I also added duplicate references to the image both via the `background-image` CSS property, and the `background` HTML attribute (because god knows what the Gmail preprocessor is doing).

```
<table class="table" background="https://www.example.com/image.jpg/" style="background-image: url(https://www.example.com/image.jpg/);">
```

<sup><sub>*This won't work for Outlook, as Outlook [doesn't support background images *at all*](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/).</sub></sup>

---

A couple of other ideas for your case: make sure the link is actually up and make sure the server is correctly configured to externally serve whatever kind of image this is supposed to serve up.

If all else fails, maybe you could try using a URL which resolves directly to an image.  Gmail might strip all of that out it it makes the determination that it looks too sketchy.

Comment: is this still the most up-to-date valid way to do it?

Comment: @marioruiz The approach I suggested above is quite old - I'm assuming it's easier in 2024 - not sure though.