# Adding a background over a TD element and looking for a way to do it in Gmail App

Tags: email, background, fallback

I'm adding an image as background by using [this code](https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/how-to-make-your-emails-bulletproof/#:%7E:text=Bulletproof%20email%20background%20images%20are,of%20your%20subscriber%27s%20email%20client.).

I understood in clients where the image is going to be blocked/not loaded, the best user experience we can have is a filled background color.

Is it still the most valid way to achieve this? I have a special interest in the Gmail app, as is where I see the background image is being blocked/not loaded. Thanks.

I already verified [this info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35217486/android-gmail-app-does-not-render-background-image-in-html-email)